# oAuth 1.0, Advanced Rest Client, Twitter API, Not Working

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api, advanced-rest-client

I've done all the developer.twitter.com setup (created an app and a dev environment).  In ARC, I have filled in the Authorization section, choosing oAuth 1.0, filled in the consumer key, consumer secret, token, token secret, and token auth URL. ARC created the timestamp and nonce, and I chose the HMAC-SHA1 realm.  When I click "authorize", it just hangs; never comes back.  When I try a simple GET  on api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=< my screen name >, I get the 400 "Bad authentication data" with code 215 response.  What am I missing?  I've both created and consumed many REST APIs but never had a problem using ARC for them before.

Comment: what goes for token auth URL?

Answer (score 2):

I think this PostMan image solve your solution ..
consumer key, consumer secret, token, token secret -- use only four with your API

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, Advanced Rest Client just plain doesn't work with the Twitter API.  I used Insomnia instead, and it worked with the exact same inputs that I gave to ARC.  ARC has been a great tool for me for the past decade, so it's disappointing.